# Как скопом удалить всех юзеров которые Pending?

Tags: wordpress

Как скопом удалить всех юзеров которые Pending (в ожидании), если в phpmyadmin их нет, а в админке их 10000+?

Answer (score 2):

В интернетах (например, [тут](http://dailyblogging.org/wordpress/delete-pending-posts-in-wordpress/)) предлагают несколько способов.

Через SQL-запрос:

```
DELETE 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_date < '2015-01-01 00:00:00' 
AND post_status = 'pending'
```

Через плагины wordpress, если не умеете первым способом:

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mass-delete/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-delete/